# Toggle class inside anchor

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to toggle create a dynamic toggle for a dropdown using the font awesome set. Here's my html:

```
<div id="contis" class="row">
    <div class="container contis">
        <div class="minispc"></div>

        <a href="#service1" data-toggle="collapse"><i class = "fas fa-chevron-right"></i> Service 1</a>
        <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            <div class="collapse" id = "service1">
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and the js I have so far:

```
$('contis > a').click(function() {
    $('i', this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
```

However when I click it, nothing happens. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the selector. Add a `#`:

```
$('#contis a').click(function() {
    $('i', this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
```

The selector you had was a tag selector, named `contis`, which would have selected `<contis>` and not anything with `id="contis"`. For `id` selector, you need to use `#contis`, which will select the right one.

Also, there's no direct descendent so remove `>`.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $('#contis a').click(function() {
    $('i', this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contis" class="row">
  <div class="container contis">
    <div class="minispc"></div>
    <a href="#service1" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> Service 1</a>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="collapse" id="service1">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please change your `class` from `fas` to `fa`.

Comment: OK so I tried running this in a fiddle and it works fine. However, when running it inside my page it fails to work?

Comment: @S.L. For some reason, your `<i>` has been converted to `<svg>`. Strange. https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0DbZ.png

Comment: @S.L. What's this script doing here? `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/js/all.js`

Comment: That's the font awesome script, the newest version, 5.0